# Converting Linkedin OAuth 1.0 tokens to OAuth 2.0

Tags: linkedin-api

Like many of you, we are caught in LinkedIn's sudden unannounced change to their Company API.

We've worked out an OAuth 2.0 solution, but we don't want to put all of our users through a scenario where they are forced to come back to our apps and re-connect to linkedin under OAuth2.0 if possible.

I'm wondering if there's an "exchange tokens" method where I can send Linkedin valid OAuth 1.0 tokens and get back a valid OAuth 2.0 token?  I seem to recall other services have assisted in migrating tokens but can't find anything on Linkedin's sparse documentation to suggest that they have such a feature.

If anyone knows about an endpoint I can call to convert, I and others would definitely take interest.

TIA,

DW

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do that. You will need to implement OAuth 2.0 to get an OAuth 2.0 token